# Performance with ADO.NET large data retrieval in ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ado.net

**Application** is written in **.NET Core 2.1** and **Database** is **SQL Server 2014**.

There is a page which has to retrieve 80-100 thousand rows of data from SQL Server. I've added indexes to the columns I deemed appropriate and the query can return all the rows in around 5 seconds. So, as the application has to then iterate all these rows and create view model objects, it takes another 6-8 seconds to loop and do all the logic necessary. This results in a total load time of about 16-17 seconds.

Before anyone suggests using pagination, this view is designed to look like an Excel worksheet and does a bunch of CSS fun to make it look presentable. As I can't find any more optimization of the loop in the backend and I have compressed the View being returned via IIS Compress Dynamic option, I thought the only other thing to do to maybe shave some time off the load would be to query the database in batches. I tested a run of doing a batch of 10000 at a time and that returned in SQL Management in less than 1 second. So I coded things to fire off a `Task<DataTable>` that creates it's own database connection and queries for its batch of 10000 records and do this in a loop creating enough tasks to cover the amount of records needing to be returned. This works off a previous query that returns a MIN and a MAX identity value for the given range of records, the range is off of a date range of pay periods. I then do an `await Task.WhenAll()` on each of these tasks thinking that this would improve the wait time on the initial pull of the data from SQL. I've found that this results in about the same if not worse wait time.

I'm out of ideas as to how to improve performance at this point and was hoping someone may be able to suggest another idea. I'll provide my `Task<DataTable>` approach to calling the database for chunks of data so that you can see if I may have done something wrong.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DataTable>> GetOverViewInfoChunk(List<int> disciplineIds, List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> statuses, DateTime startWeek, DateTime endWeek, long firstId, long lastId, int batchNumber = 10000)
{
     DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
     string procName = _config.GetValue<string>(nameof(GetOverViewInfoChunk));
     IList<Task<DataTable>> tablelistTasks = new List<Task<DataTable>>();
     long rangeCounter = firstId + batchNumber - 1;
     IEnumerable<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();
     while (true)
     {
          Dictionary<string, string> @params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
          @params.Add("@disciplines", _sqlHelper.GetDisciplinesForTopAndBottom3(disciplineIds).ToString());
          @params.Add("@startWeekDate", startWeek.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
          @params.Add("@lastWeekDate", endWeek.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
          @params.Add("@jobStatuses", _sqlHelper.GetJobOverviewStatuses(statuses).ToString());
          @params.Add("@firstId", firstId.ToString());
          @params.Add("@lastId", rangeCounter > lastId ? lastId.ToString() : rangeCounter.ToString());
          tablelistTasks.Add(new Classes.SQLActionHelper(_config.GetValue<string>("Data:XXXX")).GetBatch(procName, @params));
                
           //Increment range vars
           firstId += batchNumber;
           rangeCounter += batchNumber;
                
           if (firstId > lastId)
             break;
      }
         
      try
      { 
          tables = await Task.WhenAll(tablelistTasks);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

      }

      TimeSpan benchMark = DateTime.Now - now;
      return tables;
}   

//class for querying the data in batches
public class SQLActionHelper
{
    private string _connStr;

    public SQLActionHelper(string connStr)
    {
        _connStr = connStr;
    }

    public async Task<DataTable> GetBatch(string procName, Dictionary<string, string> @params)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        //create the connection object and command object
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procName, conn))
            {
                //Open the connection
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                //its a stored procedure
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //Add key value pairs to the command for passing parameters to sql proc or query
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in @params)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }


                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No actual person can deal with 80k-100K rows at a time? Surely there is some filtering possible? TBH getting that many rows to the front end in 17s seems quite reasonable? There are going to be significant delays when moving that much data around...

Comment: @DaleK Thank you for your response. I've re-evaluated my design and I believe I have found a better way of managing data. It's good to know that I was at least in the ballpark for response time when dealing with that much data. I may delete or close this post once I see if the new design fixes the whole problem.

Comment: Calling the database multiple times concurrently isn't going to be faster if the bottleneck is IO. You probably need some kind of pagination in the user interface instead. Look at [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), it is much more performant than other methods. You shouldn't pass date parameters as strings, pass them through as `date` or `datetime`.

Comment: Thank you for your response Charlieface. I return the dates as Date. Pagination is not an option client side due to client requirements. I changed some logic on how I was storing data in the DB and I've reduced the number of rows needing pulled from the database to a few thousand. Load time is down to a few seconds. I may leave this post open in case it brings some good suggestions or answers

Comment: Without seeing the actual query, table and index definitions, and query plan, can't really advise further

Comment: @Charlieface You did great. I appreciate your suggestions. The whole problem came from storing superfluous data. I modified the application to only store database records as needed, it reduced storage from 10's of thousands of records to a few thousand. By fixing the design flaw, it then reduced the amount of data needing transferred and consequently the load time.

Comment: If you have more than about 2,000 items, no amount of CSS will be able to make it presentable. It's just not something a human is capable of reviewing, and there are peer-reviewed studies that prove this. If this is intended for human consumption, rather than being read by another machine, you **NEED** to find a way to filter down the data first, before showing it to the user.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Each database record represents an employee's assigned work hours based on a work week and job. These are then pressed into a single row along with other employee work records to form one tabular row for the job. The actual view presents about 320 - 400 rows. It's compacted into a View that mimics an Excel worksheet. I have implemented multiple filters and search features which can reduce the amount of data visible to the user. So your statement about finding a way to filter down the data is already covered. But thank you for your comment.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The client wanted a view which has a header representing an employe with their employee name shown vertically in the header and underneath of that, there assigned work hours for the course of the next 3 weeks, each row is a job number with various job information and then the assigned hours over the course of those 3 weeks per employee. I'd give you a graphical example but I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: Sounds like a case of the client not knowing what they're asking for. If there are more than 2,000 or so jobs (rows) in the spreadsheet view, they won't be able to effectively manage this data. Again... there's science to prove this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I believe you Joel. Unfortunately, I am at the mercy of the client. I don't get to say "this won't work" and they actually listen to me. I am just expected to find ways to make things work the way they want it. To be honest, I warned them about this view before any development started and design decisions were being made. Starting with just an outline on paper (Word Document), I told them this was a bad decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the slow response time was not due to bad query plans, or no indexing on database tables, or the necessity of pagination or inefficient technology. The problem was that I over looked the most basic problem. **Superfluous data**.

While I admit it is somewhat embarrassing that I overlooked such a glaring design flaw, I think it is important to remember that when storing data, especially if it needs to be retrieved and presented to a user later, the first thing to look at is: "What is necessary?". While database storage is relatively inexpensive these days, the cost of retrieving it and presenting it is not.

I understand that this post in its entirety is cause for close as it's not reproducible or a coding problem per se, but more of a design flaw. Perhaps it will draw some suggestions that can be helpful to SO users. I'll leave this decision up to the community and moderators. Thank you to those who have offered comments.